# Google Chrome: Address bar search in Amazon.com searches Super User instead

Tags: google-chrome, search

I often use Chrome's "press Tab to search this website" feature in the address bar.

Somehow, Chrome is searching Super User when I press tab for amazon.com.

Is there a way to correct a mis-directed address bar search in Chrome?

Comment: ...Isn't that an improvement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following process to remove and re-add the search methods for amazon.com and/or superuser.com.

Go to the wrench menu, Options, Basics tab. In the section for Default search, click the Manage button.* In the list of search engines, remove amazon.com and/or superuser.com.

To re-add the search items, simply visit superuser.com (Chrome finds the search link in the head section of the HTML code) or preform a blank search on amazon.com (Chrome remembers the search URL). Once the search items reappear in the list, you can use the "press tab to search" functionality again.

(* Just found a shortcut: Right-click the address box and choose "Edit search engines".)

Comment: "Edit search engines" did the trick.

Answer (score 4):

You can right click inside the search box of a site, and you should see an option called "Add as search engine..."

Click that option, then you can edit the name of the entry on the search engines list, the keyword used to activate it using the Tab key, and Chrome will automatically fill in the search URL for you. If there are any conflicts with your entries, you'll see a validation icon to the right of each field; if they're all green check marks, you're good to go.

As noted above, right clicking the address box itself gives you the option to bring up the search engine manager, where you can delete and alter any entries. I just had to delete my Amazon entry and recreate it using the method I just described to get it working again. Right clicked inside the search box out of curiosity and found this nifty little trick.